# Interpretation of "Deux droites confondues" in (mathematical) context

Tags: traduction, mathématiques

I am reading a French geometry textbook that says the following:

> Pour ce qui va nous intéresser ici, deux droites qui ne se rencontrent pas (ou sont confondues) sont dites parallèles.

My English translation of this is as follows:

*For what interests us, two straight lines who never meet (or are combined) are said to be parallel.*

I'm wondering how the "(*ou sont confondues*)" should be interpreted in the context. Two lines that "combine" are **not** parallel, so it seems to me that this should be interpreted as saying that two straight lines who never meet, *or are never combined*, are said to be parallel. Is this interpretation correct?

I would appreciate it if people would please clarify this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103157/discussion-on-question-by-the-pointer-interpretation-of-deux-droites-confondues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Confondues*** doesn't mean "combined", it's closer to "confused" when it means indistinguishable.

So *deux droites confondues* means two straigth lines that are impossible to distinguish from each other, i.e. two straight lines that might have different definitions but that share all of their points.

See the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/confondue):

> **CONFONDRE**, verbe trans.
>   **I.−** [L'accent est mis sur l'idée de non-distinction]
>   **A.−** Mêler si étroitement (soit plusieurs choses ou personnes, soit une chose ou une personne à un ensemble) qu'il n'est plus possible de les distinguer.

Etymologically, *confondre* means *fondre ensemble*, i.e. melt together.

Note: In geometry, the definition of parallel lines is the set of lines that share the very same direction (*vecteur directeur*). That means any given line is parallel with itself.

When we want to exclude that case, we say *droites strictement parallèles*.

Comment: The technical term in English is "coincident lines". It exists in French too but "*confondu*" is more common, it seems.